# Need a regex using java

Tags: java, regex

```
    **************************
    * Ending Case(test) *
    **************************
SET: Global["test_status"]=FAILED
=========================
= Ending Test (test) =
=========================
```

Regex which will return the status i.e. FAILED or PASSED from the above text.

Currently I'm using

```
.*SET: Global\\W"test_status"\\W=(.*)
```

But it returns

```
FAILED
=========================
= Ending Test (test) =
=========================
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
^SET: Global\["test_status"\]=(.*)$
```

Represented as a Java string:

```
"^SET: Global\\[\"test_status\"\\]=(.*)$"
```

**EDIT:** This pattern should be used with `Pattern.MULTILINE`, but not `Pattern.DOTALL`.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I've updated the answer; can you try that expression?

Comment: Its not working. Its not even matching. For compilation, I'm using Pattern.compile( regex, Pattern.DOTALL ). I've tried with and without 'Pattern.DOTALL' but still :(

Comment: Use Pattern.MULTILINE but *not* DOTALL.  MULTILINE will make the ^ and $ anchors match *any* line in the string, not the beginning and end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

One problem with using .* is it doesn't stop at the end of the line. Try something like this:

```
^SET: Global\["test_status"\]=(.*)$
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally it worked

```
.*SET: Global\\[\"test_status\"\\]=(.*)\\r\\n=.*\\r\\n= Ending .*
```

Comment: This is way more complicated than it needs to be.  Use my pattern with Pattern.MULTILINE.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
"(?m)=(\\w+)\\b"
```

as the argument to **Pattern.compile()**

You don't need much context in this example. The pattern is just the multi-line flag **(?m)** followed by an '**=**' character as context and a capturing group **(\\w+)** delimited by a word boundary marker **\\b**

Use the **find()** method on the **Matcher** and extract group 1.